# Angular breadcrumb with nested routes

Tags: angular, angular6

I am displaying Breadcrumb by following below example.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s4fvjg)

I tried to add Nested Routes for the example as mentioned below

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
    path: '',
    children:[{
      path: '',
      component: CustomerListComponent
    },{
      path: 'customer',
      component: CustomerComponent,
      data:{breadcrumb:'customer'}
    }
    ]

  }
];
```

It is navigating to the next route as expected but the url is not getting added into the bread crumb.

is there any mistake I did or do we need to do anything else.

Comment: you provided a wrong stackblitz link. check it once

Comment: @Anil updated the link, can you check once

Comment: The stackblitz updated is working fine. The url is getting added to the bread crumb

Comment: yaa it is working fine, my question is if i add child routes into the customerModule, the child routes is not getting added into the breadcrumb

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the code it's not working with children routes,

But when I'm using ng6-breadcrumbs it's working fine.[ng6-breadcrumbs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng6-breadcrumbs)

Forked [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s4fvjg-an2fn4)